# Does Angular 2 have an 'equivalent' to componentDidMount in ReactJS

Tags: angular

I'm able to apply some GSAPI effects to dynamically generated graphics by placing the required code in componentDidMount() in a React-based application.

I've tried using a Promise and placing the same code in the 'next' method, but it seem to execute "too early" so the GSAPI effects are not created.

Suggestions welcome:)

Comment: The Promise-related comment refers to an Angular 2 application.

Comment: ANSWER: the ngAfterContentInit() method works for my use case

Answer (score 11):

@Oswald I think you are doing some manipulation of DOM after component is rendered so `ngAfterContentInit` seems to be appropriate for this case.

There are other lifecycle methods available as well. Have a look here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html#!#hooks-overview

Comment: ngAfterViewInit is also ok for that purpose (more info please read: https://medium.com/@zizzamia/the-secret-life-cycle-of-components-ee180a9a42bb